# Showing the equivalence of two definitions of non degeneracy and question about non degeneracy of symplectic form

Tags: linear-algebra, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

I have the usual definition of non degeneracy for a differential 2-form in a vector space V.
For every $v \in V:$ $\omega(v,u)=0 \,, \forall u \in V$ $\Rightarrow v=0$
and the definition given in my lecture:
$\forall x \neq 0\    \exists u \in V: \omega(v,u)=0$

the second definition immediately follows from the first one, but I am having trouble showing the other side, if this statement is even correct at all. Leading to my second question
How is the symplectic form non degenerate, if there exists a subspace $U \subset V$ such that,
$U^{\perp_{\omega}}=\{v \in V |\omega(v,u)=0\quad \forall u \in U\}$.
especially considering that $\omega$ is antisymmetric it would follow that
$\forall x \neq 0: \omega(x,x)=0$, which would mean we cannot conclude that $x$ has to be $0$.
Can anyone enlighten me where I am going wrong, since I am sure, the literature is correct this time.

Edit:
I already noticed my mistakes. Assume $\omega(v,u)=0$ for all $u \in V$, but since $\forall u \in V :\exists v \in V: \omega(v,u)\neq 0$, the assumption must be false.
The second question is along the same vein, that i have not considered, that it needs to hold for all elements in V.

Comment: Hey! Not sure if it's a typo or not, but the second definition should be: $\forall v \neq 0 \exists u \in V : \omega(v,u) \neq 0$. If that wasn't the thing that confused you, I can write an answer if you want, but in short: the equivalence between the two definition is a straight forward exercise in logic (and I'm not sure what you're asking regarding the symplectic subspace and its complement).

Comment: yeah the problem was that i got the definition wrong and it confused me.